# Python Wheel of Fortune accept the whole word

Tags: python

I am doing a simple wheel of fortune program in python. I want the user to be able to win the game at any time by guessing the whole word, not just one letter at a time. How can I do that?
That's the logic of my code:

```
while guess in used:
        print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
        
    used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")
        prize = random.randrange(500, 5000)
        money = money + (prize* (correct+1))

        # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
                correct = correct + 1
            else:
                new += so_far[i]              
        so_far = new

    elif guess == word:
        print("YAY! You guessed the word.")
        prize = random.randrange(500, 5000)
        money = money + (prize* (correct+1)) # part where I am struggling with


    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
```

Used is the chars used and guess is the user's input

edit:

```
if so_far == word:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")
    print("\nThe word was", word)
    print("\nYour cash prize is: ", money)
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct? It looks like everything starting from `used.append(guess)` should be unindented one level.

Comment: The `elif guess == word:` block should break out of the loop that asks for more letters.

Comment: Don't you also need to check if `so_far == word`? Is that done somewhere else?

Comment: yeah the `so_far == word` part I have. Sorry I haven't included it in the beginning I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code here to check if `so_far` is the whole word. I guess that's done after this code.

So just set `so_far` to the word when they guess the whole word. Then that other code will declare them the winner.

You also need to skip the `if guess in word:` test when `guess` is more than one character.

```
if len(guess) == 1 and guess in word:
    print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")
    prize = random.randrange(500, 5000)
    money = money + (prize* (correct+1))

    # create a new so_far to include guess
    new = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
            correct = correct + 1
        else:
            new += so_far[i]              
    so_far = new

elif guess == word:
    print("YAY! You guessed the word.")
    prize = random.randrange(500, 5000)
    money = money + (prize* (correct+1)) # part where I am struggling with
    so_far = word # add this line

else:
    print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
```

Comment: I'm confused on where exactly should I add the `guess == word` part in the loop. after `if so_far == word`?

Comment: It should be exactly where it is.

Comment: All you need to do is add the one line `so_far = word` to your existing code. And fix the indentation.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't go through the loop of `elif guess == word:` and goes through `if guess in word:`

Comment: I'm guessing it's indentation but I don't see why it wouldn't work if elif is aligned under if

Comment: It should be aligned that way. The problem is that `if` is indented inside `while`'

Comment: Oh, the problem is that `if string1 in string2:` succeeds when `string1` is a substring of `string2`, which is also the case when they're equal. You should only do the `in` test when `guess` is 1 character long.